# .htaccess redirect all images in image folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Ok, so I have a small predicament. I have a large image gallery that has over 30,000 images inside of it. I've decided to change to a newer piece of software, and this new gallery is completely different in the way image URLs are handled. So a simple redirect isn't going to cut it anymore (there is no way to determine a connection between A and B, per se, because the old gallery used ID's whereas the new one uses titles for SEO).

However, I would like to still accomodate to the old URL's by redirecting visitors to the corresponding image files. The script that they were contained within maybe gone, but the database and ID's of each image are still there - I was thinking to just rename every image file to the match the ID in the database, and use a redirect rule somehow to link to them.

The old URL structure looked something like this:

```
domain.com/image/3343/
```

All of the images are contained within the /images/ folder. If I rename every image filename to match the ID's (as above), how can I use htaccess to redirect the URLs to these files?

Keep in mind.. I need a solution that doesn't involve 30,000 rows in a htaccess file :)

Comment: What should `/image/3343/` be redirected to?

Comment: To for example, /image/3343.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/image/([0-9]+)/$ /image$1.jpg
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^image/([0-9]+)/$ /image/$1.jpg [L,R=301]
```

---

For inside the image folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ /image/$1.jpg [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Looks good. Is there a way to get this working with htaccess INSIDE the image folder? With this method the htaccess has to be in root, correct?

Comment: @Pete yeah, that's written to match within the document root, see edit above